# FilledButton material in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

What's the difference between [FilledButton.tonalIcon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilledButton/FilledButton.tonalIcon.html) and [FilledButton.icon](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/FilledButton/FilledButton.icon.html) ?
I checked their constructor, both is same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flutter, FilledButton.tonalIcon and FilledButton.icon are the same, as you observed. Both constructors are available for creating buttons with icons. However, they might be named differently for clarity or consistency within a library or framework.
f you're seeing both constructors and they have identical implementations and parameters, it's likely that they are aliases or synonyms provided for convenience or to maintain consistency in the API.

In such cases, you can use either FilledButton.tonalIcon or FilledButton.icon interchangeably to create a button with an icon, and they should behave the same way. The choice between them may depend on personal preference or the naming conventions adopted within the project or library you're working with.

Answer (score 1):

There is a comma difference between the button

For:

```
1)  FilledButton.icon(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: const Icon(Icons.home),
            label: const Text('Hello'),
   ),
```

You have to give icon because that is required

```
   2)  FilledButton.tonal(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: const Text('Hello'),
      ),
```

You don't need to give icon because that is not required

Comment: thanks for your answer, but what I mean was  `FilledButton.tonalIcon` and `FilledButton.icon`

Comment: I think there is only a diffrence between them 

1)FilledButton.icon will take primary color from them
2)FilledButton.tonal will take foreground color from them